# Angular autofocus on element when visible

Tags: angular, angular-directive, autofocus

I was asked to update on a frontend application with Angular 8 to set autofocus on a particular element.  Basically, this app would prompt user to enter a question and the app would display some result text which needs to be focused.

I have searched and tried a few suggestions using Angular autofocus directives but not succeed. I find a lot of samples on using autofocus for input field but not for div.

Is it possible to set autofocus on this  element without reloading the page?  If so, how do I do that?

**Update** - I found this tutorial but it doesn't exactly do as I hoped.  I thought the input field should automatically be focused when the page is loaded.  However, it's only focused if I have to click/tab.
https://www.codementor.io/@yomateo/auto-focus-with-angular-7-the-directive-osfcl7rrv

Is there a way to have autofocus on the field without actual click or tab?

Comment: Please post yout code what you have tried so far. It will help in providing the solution or rectify if there is anything wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things

- make sure the code you are ttying to focus on input field is correct. You can check it out by calling on some button click.
- check calling this code inside some different lifecycle hook such as ngAfterContentInit() , ngAfterViewChecked() or any other.
- If 2nd point doesn't help then try putting your code inside timeout.

Comment: Do you know any samples out there that do what you have described?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`cdkTrapFocusAutoCapture`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview#focustrap) from `@angular/cdk`